# Dynamic Filtering a Dataframe based date in Pandas with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a dataframe based on date field.

```
 Date    Value
201810   100
201811   150
201812   95
201901   125
201902   150
201903   200
201904   225
```

The filtering is to be done dynamically. E.g. the first date and end date should not be 'hard coded'.
So my approach is as follows:

```
month = pd.DataFrame(set(df['Date']),columns=['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y%m)
```

From here, I have to filter based on date and create a new dataframe. In this the last date, say 201903.

```
dt_first = month['Date'].head(1)   <---first date is being dynamically created
dt_last = month.iloc[-2]           <-- last date, dynamically created. 
df_filter = df[(df.Date.ge(dt_first))&(df.Date.le(dt_last))]
```

But the last line is generating a blank dataframe. The resultant dataframe should look like

```
 Date    Value
 201810   100
 201811   150
 201812   95
 201901   125
 201902   150
 201903   200
```

I know I am missing out something.

Can anybody please suggest how to effectively filter the above dataframe based on condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is necessary compare by scalar, so is extracted first and last value of column by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

Btw, if compare by `ge` for greater or equal in sorted values with first val it match all data, so this condition always return Trues, so should be removed with same output:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y%m')

df_filter = df[(df.Date.ge(df['Date'].iat[0]))&(df.Date.lt(df['Date'].iat[-1]))]
```

Same like:

```
df_filter = df[(df.Date.lt(df['Date'].iat[-1]))]

print (df)
        Date  Value
0 2018-10-01    100
1 2018-11-01    150
2 2018-12-01     95
3 2019-01-01    125
4 2019-02-01    150
5 2019-03-01    200
6 2019-04-01    225
```

Comment: isn't `lt` would be replaced by `le`

Comment: @pythondumb - If replace to `le` get same output, used `lt` for remove last row

Comment: Thanks jezrael. So `le` actually solved my purpose with `iat[5]`. BTW, I have posted another question. please check at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169977/pandas-group-by-operation-on-dynamically-selected-columns-with-conditional-filt